# What testing advice will you give a beginner for testing websites

Tags: testing

I'm just starting out working on test scripts.I'm going to get a web application created in .net for testing. I have no idea what kind of testing is needed for such kind of applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is that you should have a healthy mix of automated and manual testing.

**AUTOMATED TESTING**

- **Unit Testing**
  Use NUnit to test your classes, functions and interaction between them.
  http://www.nunit.org/index.php
- **Automated Functional Testing**
  If it's possible you should automate a lot of the functional testing. Some frame works have functional testing built into them. Otherwise you have to use a tool for it. If you are developing web sites/applications you might want to look at Selenium.
  http://www.peterkrantz.com/2005/selenium-for-aspnet/
- **Continuous Integration**
  Use CI to make sure all your automated tests run every time someone in your team makes a commit to the project.
  http://martinfowler.com/articles/continuousIntegration.html

**MANUAL TESTING**
As much as I love automated testing it is, IMHO, not a substitute for manual testing. The main reason being that an automated can only do what it is told and only verify what it has been informed to view as pass/fail. A human can use it's intelligence to find faults and raise questions that appear while testing something else.

- **Exploratory Testing**
  ET is a very low cost and effective way to find defects in a project. It take advantage of the intelligence of a human being and a teaches the testers/developers more about the project than any other testing technique i know of. Doing an ET session aimed at every feature deployed in the test environment is not only an effective way to find problems fast, but also a good way to learn and fun!
  http://www.satisfice.com/articles/et-article.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A web application should go through below test's

```
1) Functionality Testing
2) Usability testing
3) Interface testing
4) Compatibility testing
5) Performance testing
6) Security testing
```

for complete guide
[Read this Article](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/web-application-testing/)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of small things that you may need to check (assuming you're doing manual testing):

Check for the exact location/alignment of items
Check whether all hyperlinks are working as expected
Check by clicking a button (submitting the form) multiple time
Check for security aspects (google for xss or cross site scripting)
Check for fonts etc. (if they're different from standards)

Hope this helps.